# pandas - how to select rows based on a conjunction of a non indexed column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

Consider the following DataFrame -

```
In [47]: dati                                                                                        
Out[47]: 
                      x      y
frame face lmark              
1     NaN  NaN      NaN    NaN
300   0.0  1.0    745.0  367.0
           2.0    753.0  411.0
           3.0    759.0  455.0
2201  0.0  1.0    634.0  395.0
           2.0    629.0  439.0
           3.0    630.0  486.0
```

How can we select the rows where dati['x'] > 629.5 for **all rows** sharing the same value in the 'frame' column. For this example, I would expect to result to be

```
                      x      y
frame face lmark              
300   0.0  1.0    745.0  367.0
           2.0    753.0  411.0
           3.0    759.0  455.0
```

because column 'x' of 'frame' 2201, 'lmark' 2.0 is not greater than 629.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) for test if all `True`s per groups and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = dat[(dat['x'] > 629.5).groupby(level=0).transform('all')]
print (df)
                      x      y
frame face lmark              
300   0.0  1.0    745.0  367.0
           2.0    753.0  411.0
           3.0    759.0  455.0
```

Comment: Excellent answer - thanks! I have searched everywhere for the documentation of GroupBy.transform. Did you find it?

Comment: @user2309803 - Yes, you can check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation)

Comment: I discovered another solution using a boolean array which performs the comparison for each group of 'frame' `bool_array = (dati['x'] > 629.5).all(level='frame')` and then use its index to access the DataFrame `dati.loc[bool_array.index[bool_array]]`